# calling jQuery effect without an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a function call SwapOnscreenPhotos. Here is the source for that function:

```
function SwapOnscreenPhotos(currentPhotoSet, arrowClicked)
{
    $("#photo-list img").each(function(index) 
    { 
        $(this).attr("src", photoData[currentPhotoSet][index].url);

        if (photoData[currentPhotoSet][index].liked === true)
        {   
            $(this).addClass("liked");
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).removeClass("liked");
        }
    });

    //Animate the old photos off of the screen
    $("#match").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
}
```

I do some random things, and then at the end of the function, I want to call an effect on #match unconditionally. There is no event after which I want to execute this effect (if it matters, an event determines whether I call SwapOnScreenPhotos in the first place). How am I supposed to execute this effect?

**EDIT:**

Sorry, let me clarify myself. I had gotten the impression that every jQuery expression follows a similar formula. `$('selector').event(function() { //function stuff});`

My code `$("#match").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);` deviates sharply from this example. My code more closely resembles the following model: `$('selector').function`.  Notice that there is no event that dictates when my code should be executed and when it should not be executed.  Is there a way to call jQuery functions without this event?  When I try run the above code, I am given this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Property '#' of object # is not a function jquery.js:8780
>       Tween.run jquery.js:8780
>       tick jquery.js:8491
>       jQuery.fx.timer jquery.js:9032
>       Animation jquery.js:8555
>       jQuery.fn.extend.animate.doAnimation jquery.js:8871
>       jQuery.extend.dequeue jquery.js:1894
>       jQuery.fn.extend.queue jquery.js:1937
>       jQuery.extend.each jquery.js:611
>       jQuery.fn.jQuery.each jquery.js:241
>       jQuery.fn.extend.queue jquery.js:1930
>       jQuery.fn.extend.animate jquery.js:8881
>       jQuery.each.jQuery.fn.(anonymous function) jquery.js:8853
>       AnimateMatch match.js:21
>       SwapOnscreenPhotos match.js:70
>       $.ajax.success match.js:167
>       jQuery.Callbacks.fire jquery.js:974
>       jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith jquery.js:1082
>       done jquery.js:7650
>       jQuery.ajaxTransport.send.callback

I assumed that this error was caused by my failure to specify an event.  Does this make more sense?
Thank you

Comment: HUH? What are you asking exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use the [JQuery UI `hide`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/hide/); this is the error message you get if the JQuery UI library hasn't been loaded, and you're instead working with [plain JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).

For example, if I run your code on this (Stack Overflow) page using Firebug, then I get the same error.

```
$("body").hide("slide", { direction: "left" });
```

> TypeError: Property '#' of object # is not a function

---

So in summary, there's nothing wrong with how you're trying to call the function.  I think the problem is that you've neglected to include the JQuery UI library, or it hasn't been loaded correctly.

Answer (score 2):

> I had gotten the impression that every jQuery expression follows a similar formula. $('selector').event(function() { //function stuff});

No that is not the case. Not everything is a reaction to an event. You can call:

```
$("#match").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
```

Anytime you want after the DOM is ready and the action will be performed on the selected element.

The error youre getting is probably happening because you are trying to use a jQuery element selection before the DOM is ready. This is why you typically wrap anything that needs to select elements inside an onReady attachment. This way the js doesnt execute until the DOM is parsed and can be used.

```
$(function(){
   // this will execute as soon as the DOM is ready
   $("#match").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
});
```

onReady is similar to onLoad but happens before because onLoad waits for external assets (like images) to be loaded where as onReady happens as soon as the DOM is loaded.